# How to add a mask on top of a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

In my application I am using a UI collection view that strictly scrolls horizontally. The collection view is displayed on the very bottom of the screen at all times and has the functionality of a "photo scrubber". It allows you to quickly scrub through a photo album. I am wanting to add an aesthetic change to the appearance. Instead of this collection view being displayed linearly left to right, I want to add some sort of mask where it gives the top right and left of the collection views bounds a rounded feature. That way it will look like a partially rounded scrubber at the bottom of the page. How can I go about adding this mask on top of a collection view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this one of a few ways, either get the mask as an image and put the `UIImageView` on top of the `UICollectionView` with in the storyboard. Literally arrange it in the view hierarchy with in the storyboard.

You next best option is importing `QuartzCore` framework and setting a corner radius. This is not a mask but it will round the corners of an `UICollectionView` to give you the same effect.

If you only wanted the top part to be rounded then make the collection view have a greater height, and a greater bottom off set and just move it off the screen.

If you want to be able to see things below the `UICollectionView` but still want to have it near the bottom, your only option is an image, err i should say the quickest way is an image.

[CALayer Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html)